# ckeditor and bbcode disable smiley

Tags: ckeditor, bbcode

Do you know if it is possible to disable smiley transformation without modifying bboce source code ? (I don't want the :P change in img tag)

I have tried to clear the `ckEditor.config.smiley_images` and `ckEditor.config.smiley_description` ... but I've had no success.

Any ideas?